# Iterating through Array of Arrays generating unwanted output

Tags: php

I am having issues when iterating through an array of arrays in PHP.

I have the following array, which I have posted to the page using Ajax.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => T64 [1] => Array ( [name] => T64 [dummyA] => 2 [dummyB] 
=> 2 [dummyC] => 2 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => T65 [1] => Array ( [name] => T65 [dummyA] => 2 [dummyB] 
=> 2 [dummyC] => 2 ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => T91 [1] => Array ( [name] => T91 [dummyA] => 2 [dummyB] 
=> 2 [dummyC] => 2 ) ) )
```

I have tried to print all of the inner values using the below method, however it always prints a T (on its own line), before each desired value.

```
foreach($sOptions as $row => $innerArray){
  foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
    print $value['dummyA'] . "<br/>";
    print $value['dummyB'] . "<br/>";
    print $value['dummyC'] . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Output:

T
T
T
2
2
2
T
T
T
2
2
2
T
T
T
2
2
2

Would anyone be able to give be some incite to where these T values are coming from?

Comment: My guess is that you have not posted the same code as you got the output from

Comment: Nah) the data is valid, the iteration is a bit wrong. there should be one extra `foreach`

Comment: I agree the extra foreach, even with it, the output does not correspond

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting, and it will tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'd add a `if (is_array($value)) { print ($value['dummyA']); ... }`

Comment: I stand corrected, there is no need for extra `foreach`, anyway the accepted answet explains it inm ore detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious. You are trying to get indexed value of the actual value from second level array using a string index that does not exists.

Because any [string can be accessed as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) then the non existing string index is interpreted as false so it returns first value, ie zero-index character from the string accessed as an array.

In first case the value T64 is actually accessed as array('T','6','1') so it returned `T`.

```
<?php

// simple example
// Get the first character of a string
$str = 'T64';
echo "First character is: ". $str[0] .PHP_EOL;
echo "Second character is: ". $str[1] .PHP_EOL;
echo "Third character is: ". $str[2] .PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Applied to your code:". PHP_EOL;
$sOptions = Array ( Array ( 'T64' ) );

print_r($sOptions[0][0]['invalid string index']);
```

Look at the demo: [https://eval.in/1063420](https://eval.in/1063432)

Output:

```
First character is: T
Second character is: 6
Third character is: 4


T
```

Note: turn on error reporting to simplify your debugging ;) [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

More reading about accessing strings as array in described in [PHP manual Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) esspecialy Example #11 and later.

Answer (score 3):

can you try to use only one foreach ? I haven't try this solution but you can try to do something of similar

```
foreach($sOptions as $row => $innerArray){
    $value = $innerArray[1]
    print $value['dummyA'] . "<br/>";
    print $value['dummyB'] . "<br/>";
    print $value['dummyC'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Can I ask how this line works? $value = $innerArray[1]. I can't quite work out what it is doing.

Comment: I have simplified the code, I have taken the array and I have cycled in the array, for every element I have saved the second part of subarray in value, then I have statically taken the parts of subarray saved in value

Comment: I think @ino answer is better because it also explain the root cause for that issue - when providing just the fix OP will learn less...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_column to isolate the part you want to iterate.

```
foreach(array_column($arr,1) as $row => $value){
    echo $value['dummyA'] . "\n";
    echo $value['dummyB'] . "\n";
    echo $value['dummyC'] . "\n";
}
```

This means the code will only iterate the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "T64 "
    ["dummyA"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyB"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyC"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "T65"
    ["dummyA"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyB"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyC"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "T91 "
    ["dummyA"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyB"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
    ["dummyC"]=>
    string(2) "2 "
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YA6Vq